# Difference between "final" and "const"?

Tags: java

I know that Java uses "final" to declare a constant and that c uses "const". Just wondering what the differences are between the two.

Comment: Just making something `final` in Java doesn't make it a constant.

Comment: And why a tag for a completely unrelated language?

Comment: In Java final reference is the same as a const pointer (* const) . That is you can change the value of the data the pointer points to but you can't make the pointer point to different data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In java, making something final means that it can't be reasigned to another reference to another instance, but if it's a reference to a mutable class, the mutable values inside the class can still be modified.

For example, a final String is a constant because Strings are immutable in Java, but a final ArrayList means that you cannot assign it to another ArrayList, but you can still add and remove elements to that ArrayList